# Numbers are being converted to date format automatically while writing in Excel sheet using python Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am doing an automation of one of my report. But when I am copying values from a list i.e 'summary' to one of the sheet named 'Summary' in excel using openpyxl. It is automatically converting numbers into date. When I checked format cell in excel , cells are converted to custom field.

I tried code `cell.number_format='General'`. But it is also not working

'summary' is a list which i need to write in excel sheet named 'Summary'

```
>>>summary

[11, '19', 322, 2460, 317, 2413, 318, 4, 9, 47, 2370, 2370, 0, 0, '2455']
```

complete code which i am executing:

```
wb_obj=openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet_sumary=wb_obj['Summary']

max_col1 = sheet_sumary.max_column

m_row1 = sheet_sumary.max_row

for j in range(1,max_col1+1):

    cell=sheet_sumary.cell(row=m_row1+1,column=j)

    cell.value= (summary[j-1])

    cell.number_format='General'
```

Expected result in excel:

```
Date    Trace collection Hour   Total SMK Nodes Total SMK Cells Total Nodes TA Available    Total cells TA Available

3-Sep-19    19  322 2460    317 2413
```

Actual result in excel:

```
Date    Trace collection Hour   Total SMK Nodes Total SMK Cells Total Nodes TA Available    Total cells TA Available

11/Jan/00   19  17/Nov/00   25/Sep/06   12/Nov/00   9/Aug/06
```

Above is an example of some column and here we can see that  my data  is converted into  some arbitrary date format like column 'Total SMK Nodes', whose value should be 322, but this number is converted to `'17/Nov/00'` while writing into excel.

Comment: Please make an effort to use proper formatting in the future (there is a toolbar and help icon to help you with that). I've fixed it for you, but questions are extremely difficult to read when the code and results are just thrown in there, and many people will just disregard your question if they have to wade through stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I was not aware to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known PITA that Excel insists on inflicting on its users. There are a couple things you can do to mitigate the action.

1. It looks like your `Summary` row example has a strange mix of `int` and `str` values. I'd suggest casting these to the appropriate values as you set the cells.
2. Don't use the *General* format. If you want a number cell, use the actual *Number* formatting class. *General* is Excel's default and lets it do pretty much anything it wants.

Comment: When i am using `cell.number_format='Number'`. I am getting below error while opening excel. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error114960_05.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\automation\TA Stats tracker_SMK_3rd_Sep19.xlsx'</summary><repairedRecords><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)</repairedRecord></repairedRecords></recoveryLog>`

Comment: @RoushanAnand: my guess is that you're trying to write a string into a Number field. Try setting the value to `int(value)` instead of just `value`.

Comment: I have changed code to `cell.value=int(summary[j-1])`.Also try to write only int value & removed manually any string. But still getting same error. message thrown by excel `We found a problem with some content in test.xlsx. Do you want to recover as much as we can? if you trust the sourceof this workbook, click yes` and when digging down i got error which i mentioned in my above comment.